# USERS Tablespace Best Practices for Application Schema

Tags: oracle-12c, tablespaces

When creating a user/schema to hold external application data, what are best practices for the tablespaces that the user is defaulted to?

Should the user created be defaulted to the `USER` tablespace for the default tablespace?  Does this hold true for the `TEMP` tablespace?  Or should this user have a separate default and temp tablespaces created apart from the `SYSTEM` user tablespaces to hold the application data?

I tried looking for any indication of this in the Oracle documentation, but wasn't able to find anything close to what I was looking for - apologies if this is subjective in nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a best practice, and the answer is "it depends". For example, if the schema has low accesses and few data, using a different tablespace different to USERS/TEMP isn't really necessary,because you can assign a quota to user's data (in this case, creation of separated tablespaces is a merely question about organization). Conversely, if the schema has an high i/o or has a lot of data, the uses of different tablespaces is a good choice, because you can create them to a different pool of disks (for example, Oracle is installed in magnetic hard disk, and tablespace data is created on a pool of SSD). Note that: in this case, you want also a different tablespace for saving indexes